# Pointer outputs in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to understand why the following piece of code produces the output of `7`.

```
int main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int b[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int c = 5;
    int *p = a;

    printf("%d", (c[b])[p]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is pure pointer arithmatic. Read more about pointer arithmatic [here](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-pointer-arithmetic-operations/) and [here](http://www-ee.eng.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap7/section2.1.3.html)

Just FYI, `a[5]` == `5[a]` == `*(5 + a)` == `*(a + 5)`. [Related Reading](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/joke.html).

So, in your code, `c[b]` == `b[c]` == `b[5]` == `6`.

Then, `p` being equal to `a`, the base address of the `a` array, `(c[b])[p]` == `6[p]` == `6[a]`  == `a[6]` == 7.

Comment: Thank you, you are always very helpful.

Comment: Nice answer, more info at: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/joke.html

Comment: @AlterMann Thanks for the link. Vey useful. Added in my answer. :-)

Comment: [With C arrays, why is it the case that `a[5] == 5[a]`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-c-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Well, since `c` is 5, `c[b]` is the same as `b[5]`, which is 6. Since `p` points to `a`, `6[p]` is the same as `a[6]`, which is 7.